# Fixed Well Size in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, loops, grid-layout

I have a loop of text displaying on a page, with a button that cycles the loop.  Everytime I click the button, the well changes sizes, as the text is different lengths,  is there a way that I can set the well size so that with each click it stays fixed but at the same time still responsive?

```
        <div class ="col-md-6">
            <p id="quote">Delighted with my experience. Easy and comfortable. I have the utmost confidence in Scott and trust him to help me find the right vehicle for my self, family members and friends I have referred. I just purchased my 4th car from him. </p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick = "cycle()">&gt</button>                
        </div>

function cycle() {
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (testimonials.length))
document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = textimonals[randomNumber];
}
var testimonials = ["ex.", "ex.", "ex."]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `min-height` so it would stay at minimum height and be responsive as well.

```js
function cycle() {
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *    (testimonials.length))
   document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = testimonials[randomNumber];
}

var testimonials = ["ex.", "ex.", "ex.", "Delighted with my experience. Easy and comfortable. I have the utmost confidence in Scott and trust him to help me find the right vehicle for my self, family members and friends I have referred. I just purchased my 4th car from him. Delighted with my experience. Easy and comfortable. I have the utmost confidence in Scott and trust him to help me find the right vehicle for my self, family members and friends I have referred. I just purchased my 4th car from him."];
```

```css
#quote {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="col-md-6">
            <p id="quote">Delighted with my experience. Easy and comfortable. I have the utmost confidence in Scott and trust him to help me find the right vehicle for my self, family members and friends I have referred. I just purchased my 4th car from him. </p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick = "cycle()">&gt</button>                
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome @RhinoTekMN. Don't you mind to accept my answer?

Comment: I believe I did, not sure though, relatively new here, gave you an up vote though

Comment: Take a look: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just set a reasonable height that will accommodate all testimonials.

```
#quote{
    height: 300px;
}
```